# Unable to stream video over VLC in the local network

Tags: home-networking, vlc-media-player, streaming, media-server

I am attempting to get VLC streaming working, I want to do movie nights with a friend of mine living in another country, but before I stream to the internet, I ought to be able to stream locally - which is where I hit a brick wall, no matter what streaming medium I use, the two computers are unable to connect to each other and watch the stream.

- These two computers can ping each other with a 1ms response time (5ghz wifi on the laptop)
- These two computers are both up to date windows 10 machines
- These computers can send data to each other at 37MB/s
- these two computers can stream video through windows media player flawlessly
- Both have fresh installs of vlc

Below is the log of events after I attempted to connect my desktop (192.168.31.75) to my laptop's (192.168.31.18) stream

```
main debug: processing request item: 192.168.31.18:8080, node: Playlist, skip: 0
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
main debug: starting playback of new item
main debug: resyncing on 192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: 192.168.31.18:8080 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for '192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: requesting art for new input thread
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: using timeshift path: C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Local\Temp
main debug: `http://192.168.31.18:8080' gives access `http' demux `any' path `192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='192.168.31.18:8080' file='\\192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 15 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: (path: \\192.168.31.18:8080)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 27 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
http debug: resolving 192.168.31.18 ...
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
http debug: outgoing request: GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.31.18:8080 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.12 LibVLC/3.0.12 Range: bytes=0- 
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
qt debug: IM: Setting an input
http debug: connection failed
access error: HTTP connection failure
http debug: querying proxy for http://192.168.31.18:8080
http debug: no proxy
http debug: http: server='192.168.31.18' port=8080 file=''
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.31.18 port 8080
main warning: connection timed out
http error: cannot connect to 192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: using item 0
main debug: starting playback of new item
main debug: resyncing on 192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: 192.168.31.18:8080 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for '192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: requesting art for new input thread
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: using timeshift path: C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Local\Temp
main debug: `http://192.168.31.18:8080' gives access `http' demux `any' path `192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='192.168.31.18:8080' file='\\192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 15 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: (path: \\192.168.31.18:8080)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 27 candidates
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
http debug: resolving 192.168.31.18 ...
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
http debug: outgoing request: GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.31.18:8080 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.12 LibVLC/3.0.12 Range: bytes=0- 
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
qt debug: IM: Setting an input
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
http debug: connection failed
access error: HTTP connection failure
http debug: querying proxy for http://192.168.31.18:8080
http debug: no proxy
http debug: http: server='192.168.31.18' port=8080 file=''
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.31.18 port 8080
main warning: connection timed out
http error: cannot connect to 192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: using item 0
main debug: starting playback of new item
main debug: resyncing on 192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: 192.168.31.18:8080 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for '192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: requesting art for new input thread
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: using timeshift path: C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Local\Temp
main debug: `http://192.168.31.18:8080' gives access `http' demux `any' path `192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='any' location='192.168.31.18:8080' file='\\192.168.31.18:8080'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 15 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.31.18:8080
main debug: (path: \\192.168.31.18:8080)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 27 candidates
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
http debug: resolving 192.168.31.18 ...
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
http debug: outgoing request: GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.31.18:8080 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.12 LibVLC/3.0.12 Range: bytes=0- 
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
qt debug: IM: Setting an input
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\suprd\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
```

I have been trying to solve this for about 7 hours now, and the most peculiar thing is that I did manage to get it working yesterday, satisfied with the result, I called it quits and when I tried to do it again later it refused to work

I am attempting to straem basic h.264+mp3 videos, while the video i succesfully streamed yesterday was an h.265, high res video.

I have no success in trying different streaming outputs like udp or using another pc on the network with a wired lan connection.

Thanks beforehand for any help you might be able to offer, if I've made any egregious formatting decisions in this post then don't hesitate to state to say so - it's my first post on a StackExchange forum.

Comment: ping works but port 8080 times out? Did you check your firewall?

Comment: For testing purposes I turned off the firewall and AV software on both computers, this did not resolve the issue

Comment: Never mind I probably didn't read enough of the logs. Sorry no further idea.